# jQuery ticker - how to remove #ticker-title

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, ticker

hoping someone can help.

I'm using jQuery's ticker plugin to display news headlines.

I need to be able to remove the title element 'titleElem' from the js (the text 'Latest news' is added via the JS so has no benefit for SEO), ideally the text needs to be physically on the page.

I've tried hiding the title using

```
$(function() { $('#ticker-title span').css("display", "none");  });
```

- but it makes the whole ticker disappear. Can anyone tell me ho i can remove it from the js itself? I've had a look and have no clue where to start.

  ```
  (function($){  
  $.fn.ticker = function(options) { 
      // Extend our default options with those provided.
      // Note that the first arg to extend is an empty object -
      // this is to keep from overriding our "defaults" object.
      var opts = $.extend({}, $.fn.ticker.defaults, options); 

      /* Get the id of the UL to get our news content from */
      var newsID = '#' + $(this).attr('id');

      /* Get the tag type - we will check this later to makde sure it is a UL tag */
      var tagType = $(this).get(0).tagName;   

      return this.each(function() { 
          /* Internal vars */
          var settings = {                
              position: 0,
              time: 0,
              distance: 0,
              newsArr: {},
              play: true,
              paused: false,
              contentLoaded: false,
              dom: {
                  contentID: '#ticker-content',
                  titleID: '#ticker-title',
                  titleElem: '#ticker-title SPAN',
                  tickerID : '#ticker',
                  wrapperID: '#ticker-wrapper',
                  revealID: '#ticker-swipe',
                  revealElem: '#ticker-swipe SPAN',
                  controlsID: '#ticker-controls',
                  prevID: '#prev',
                  nextID: '#next',
                  playPauseID: '#play-pause'
              }
          };

          // if we are not using a UL, display an error message and stop any further execution
          if (tagType != 'UL' && tagType != 'OL' && opts.htmlFeed === true) {
              debugError('Cannot use <' + tagType.toLowerCase() + '> type of element for this plugin - must of type <ul> or <ol>');
              return false;
          }

          // set the ticker direction
          opts.direction == 'rtl' ? opts.direction = 'right' : opts.direction = 'left';

          // lets go...
          initialisePage();
          /* Function to get the size of an Object*/
          function countSize(obj) {
              var size = 0, key;
              for (key in obj) {
                  if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) size++;
              }
              return size;
          };

          /* Function for handling debug and error messages */ 
          function debugError(obj) {
              if (opts.debugMode) {
                  if (window.console && window.console.log) {
                      window.console.log(obj);
                  }
                  else {
                      alert(obj);         
                  }
              }
          }   

          /* Function to setup the page */
          function initialisePage() {
              // add our HTML structure for the ticker to the DOM
              $(settings.dom.wrapperID).append('<div id="' + settings.dom.tickerID.replace('#', '') + '"><div id="' + settings.dom.titleID.replace('#', '') + '"><span><!-- --></span></div><p id="' + settings.dom.contentID.replace('#', '') + '"></p><div id="' + settings.dom.revealID.replace('#', '') + '"><span><!-- --></span></div></div>');
              $(settings.dom.wrapperID).removeClass('no-js').addClass('has-js ' + opts.direction);
              // hide the ticker
              $(settings.dom.tickerElem + ',' + settings.dom.contentID).hide();
              // add the controls to the DOM if required
              if (opts.controls) {
                  // add related events - set functions to run on given event
                  $(settings.dom.controlsID).live('click mouseover mousedown mouseout mouseup', function (e) {
                      var button = e.target.id;
                      if (e.type == 'click') {    
                          switch (button) {
                              case settings.dom.prevID.replace('#', ''):
                                  // show previous item
                                  settings.paused = true;
                                  $(settings.dom.playPauseID).addClass('paused');
                                  manualChangeContent(button);
                                  break;
                              case settings.dom.nextID.replace('#', ''):
                                  // show next item
                                  settings.paused = true;
                                  $(settings.dom.playPauseID).addClass('paused');
                                  manualChangeContent(button);
                                  break;
                              case settings.dom.playPauseID.replace('#', ''):
                                  // play or pause the ticker
                                  if (settings.play == true) {
                                      settings.paused = true;
                                      $(settings.dom.playPauseID).addClass('paused');
                                      pauseTicker();
                                  }
                                  else {
                                      settings.paused = false;
                                      $(settings.dom.playPauseID).removeClass('paused');
                                      restartTicker();
                                  }
                                  break;
                          }   
                      }
                      else if (e.type == 'mouseover' && $('#' + button).hasClass('controls')) {
                          $('#' + button).addClass('over');
                      }
                      else if (e.type == 'mousedown' && $('#' + button).hasClass('controls')) {
                          $('#' + button).addClass('down');
                      }
                      else if (e.type == 'mouseup' && $('#' + button).hasClass('controls')) {
                          $('#' + button).removeClass('down');
                      }
                      else if (e.type == 'mouseout' && $('#' + button).hasClass('controls')) {
                          $('#' + button).removeClass('over');
                      }
                  });
                  // add controls HTML to DOM
                  $(settings.dom.wrapperID).append('<ul id="' + settings.dom.controlsID.replace('#', '') + '"><li id="' + settings.dom.playPauseID.replace('#', '') + '" class="controls"></li><li id="' + settings.dom.prevID.replace('#', '') + '" class="controls"></li><li id="' + settings.dom.nextID.replace('#', '') + '" class="controls"></li></ul>');
              }
              if (opts.displayType != 'fade') {
                      // add mouse over on the content
                      $(settings.dom.contentID).mouseover(function () {
                          if (settings.paused == false) {
                              pauseTicker();
                          }
                      }).mouseout(function () {
                          if (settings.paused == false) {
                              restartTicker();
                          }
                      });
              }
              // process the content for this ticker
              processContent();
          }

          /* Start to process the content for this ticker */
          function processContent() {
              // check to see if we need to load content
              if (settings.contentLoaded == false) {
                  // construct content
                  if (opts.ajaxFeed) {
                      if (opts.feedType == 'xml') {
                          $.ajax({
                              url: opts.feedUrl,
                              cache: false,
                              dataType: opts.feedType,
                              async: true,
                              success: function(data){
                                  count = 0;  
                                  // get the 'root' node
                                  for (var a = 0; a < data.childNodes.length; a++) {
                                      if (data.childNodes[a].nodeName == 'rss') {
                                          xmlContent = data.childNodes[a];
                                      }
                                  }
                                  // find the channel node
                                  for (var i = 0; i < xmlContent.childNodes.length; i++) {
                                      if (xmlContent.childNodes[i].nodeName == 'channel') {
                                          xmlChannel = xmlContent.childNodes[i];
                                      }       
                                  }
                                  // for each item create a link and add the article title as the link text
                                  for (var x = 0; x < xmlChannel.childNodes.length; x++) {
                                      if (xmlChannel.childNodes[x].nodeName == 'item') {
                                          xmlItems = xmlChannel.childNodes[x];
                                          var title, link = false;
                                          for (var y = 0; y < xmlItems.childNodes.length; y++) {
                                              if (xmlItems.childNodes[y].nodeName == 'title') {                                                       
                                                  title = xmlItems.childNodes[y].lastChild.nodeValue;
                                              }
                                              else if (xmlItems.childNodes[y].nodeName == 'link') {                                                   
                                                  link = xmlItems.childNodes[y].lastChild.nodeValue; 
                                              }
                                              if ((title !== false && title != '') && link !== false) {
                                                  settings.newsArr['item-' + count] = { type: opts.titleText, content: '<a href="' + link + '">' + title + '</a>' };                                                  count++;                                                    title = false;                                                  link = false;
                                              }
                                          }   
                                      }       
                                  }           
                                  // quick check here to see if we actually have any content - log error if not
                                  if (countSize(settings.newsArr < 1)) {
                                      debugError('Couldn\'t find any content from the XML feed for the ticker to use!');
                                      return false;
                                  }
                                  setupContentAndTriggerDisplay();
                                  settings.contentLoaded = true;
                              }
                          });                         
                      }
                      else {
                          debugError('Code Me!'); 
                      }                       
                  }
                  else if (opts.htmlFeed) { 
                      if($(newsID + ' LI').length > 0) {
                          $(newsID + ' LI').each(function (i) {
                              // maybe this could be one whole object and not an array of objects?
                              settings.newsArr['item-' + i] = { type: opts.titleText, content: $(this).html()};
                          });     
                          setupContentAndTriggerDisplay();
                      }   
                      else {
                          debugError('Couldn\'t find HTML any content for the ticker to use!');
                          return false;
                      }
                  }
                  else {
                      debugError('The ticker is set to not use any types of content! Check the settings for the ticker.');
                      return false;
                  }                   
              }           
          }

          function setupContentAndTriggerDisplay() {

              settings.contentLoaded = true;

              // update the ticker content with the correct item
              // insert news content into DOM
              $(settings.dom.titleElem).html(settings.newsArr['item-' + settings.position].type);
              $(settings.dom.contentID).html(settings.newsArr['item-' + settings.position].content);

              // set the next content item to be used - loop round if we are at the end of the content
              if (settings.position == (countSize(settings.newsArr) -1)) {
                  settings.position = 0;
              }
              else {      
                  settings.position++;
              }           

              // get the values of content and set the time of the reveal (so all reveals have the same speed regardless of content size)
              distance = $(settings.dom.contentID).width();
              time = distance / opts.speed;

              // start the ticker animation                       
              revealContent();        
          }

          // slide back cover or fade in content
          function revealContent() {
              if(settings.play) { 
                  // get the width of the title element to offset the content and reveal
                  var offset = $(settings.dom.titleElem).width() + 20;
                  $(settings.dom.revealID).css(opts.direction, offset + 'px');
                  // show the reveal element and start the animation
                  if (opts.displayType == 'fade') {
                      // fade in effect ticker
                      $(settings.dom.revealID).hide(0, function () {
                          $(settings.dom.contentID).css(opts.direction, offset + 'px').fadeIn(opts.fadeInSpeed, postReveal);
                      });                     
                  }
                  else if (opts.displayType == 'scroll') {
                      // to code
                  }
                  else {
                      // default bbc scroll effect
                      $(settings.dom.revealElem).show(0, function () {
                          $(settings.dom.contentID).css(opts.direction, offset + 'px').show();
                          // set our animation direction
                          animationAction = opts.direction == 'right' ? { marginRight: distance + 'px'} : { marginLeft: distance + 'px' };
                          $(settings.dom.revealID).css('margin-' + opts.direction, '0px').delay(20).animate(animationAction, time, 'linear', postReveal);
                      });     
                  }
              }
              else {
                  return false;                   
              }
          };

          // here we hide the current content and reset the ticker elements to a default state ready for the next ticker item
          function postReveal() {             
              if(settings.play) {     
                  // we have to separately fade the content out here to get around an IE bug - needs further investigation
                  $(settings.dom.contentID).delay(opts.pauseOnItems).fadeOut(opts.fadeOutSpeed);
                  // deal with the rest of the content, prepare the DOM and trigger the next ticker
                  if (opts.displayType == 'fade') {
                      $(settings.dom.contentID).fadeOut(opts.fadeOutSpeed, function () {
                          $(settings.dom.wrapperID)
                              .find(settings.dom.revealElem + ',' + settings.dom.contentID)
                                  .hide()
                              .end().find(settings.dom.tickerID + ',' + settings.dom.revealID)
                                  .show()
                              .end().find(settings.dom.tickerID + ',' + settings.dom.revealID)
                                  .removeAttr('style');                               
                          setupContentAndTriggerDisplay();                        
                      });
                  }
                  else {
                      $(settings.dom.revealID).hide(0, function () {
                          $(settings.dom.contentID).fadeOut(opts.fadeOutSpeed, function () {
                              $(settings.dom.wrapperID)
                                  .find(settings.dom.revealElem + ',' + settings.dom.contentID)
                                      .hide()
                                  .end().find(settings.dom.tickerID + ',' + settings.dom.revealID)
                                      .show()
                                  .end().find(settings.dom.tickerID + ',' + settings.dom.revealID)
                                      .removeAttr('style');                               
                              setupContentAndTriggerDisplay();                        
                          });
                      }); 
                  }
              }
              else {
                  $(settings.dom.revealElem).hide();
              }
          }

          // pause ticker
          function pauseTicker() {                
              settings.play = false;
              // stop animation and show content - must pass "true, true" to the stop function, or we can get some funky behaviour
              $(settings.dom.tickerID + ',' + settings.dom.revealID + ',' + settings.dom.titleID + ',' + settings.dom.titleElem + ',' + settings.dom.revealElem + ',' + settings.dom.contentID).stop(true, true);
              $(settings.dom.revealID + ',' + settings.dom.revealElem).hide();
              $(settings.dom.wrapperID)
                  .find(settings.dom.titleID + ',' + settings.dom.titleElem).show()
                      .end().find(settings.dom.contentID).show();
          }

          // play ticker
          function restartTicker() {              
              settings.play = true;
              settings.paused = false;
              // start the ticker again
              postReveal();   
          }

          // change the content on user input
          function manualChangeContent(direction) {
              pauseTicker();
              switch (direction) {
                  case 'prev':
                      if (settings.position == 0) {
                          settings.position = countSize(settings.newsArr) -2;
                      }
                      else if (settings.position == 1) {
                          settings.position = countSize(settings.newsArr) -1;
                      }
                      else {
                          settings.position = settings.position - 2;
                      }
                      $(settings.dom.titleElem).html(settings.newsArr['item-' + settings.position].type);
                      $(settings.dom.contentID).html(settings.newsArr['item-' + settings.position].content);                      
                      break;
                  case 'next':
                      $(settings.dom.titleElem).html(settings.newsArr['item-' + settings.position].type);
                      $(settings.dom.contentID).html(settings.newsArr['item-' + settings.position].content);
                      break;
              }
              // set the next content item to be used - loop round if we are at the end of the content
              if (settings.position == (countSize(settings.newsArr) -1)) {
                  settings.position = 0;
              }
              else {      
                  settings.position++;
              }   
          }
      });  
  };  

  // plugin defaults - added as a property on our plugin function
  $.fn.ticker.defaults = {
      speed: 0.15,            
      ajaxFeed: false,
      feedUrl: '',
      feedType: 'xml',
      displayType: 'reveal',
      htmlFeed: true,
      debugMode: true,
      controls: true,
      titleText: 'LATEST NEWS',   
      direction: 'ltr',   
      pauseOnItems: 3000,
      fadeInSpeed: 600,
      fadeOutSpeed: 300
  };  

  })(jQuery);
  ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to SET IT AS AN EMPTY STRING... Look

```
$(function () {
  $('#js-news').ticker(
    speed: 0.10,           // The speed of the reveal
    ajaxFeed: false,       // Populate jQuery News Ticker via a feed
    feedUrl: false,        // The URL of the feed
                       // MUST BE ON THE SAME DOMAIN AS THE TICKER
    feedType: 'xml',       // Currently only XML
    htmlFeed: true,        // Populate jQuery News Ticker via HTML
    debugMode: true,       // Show some helpful errors in the console or as alerts
                       // SHOULD BE SET TO FALSE FOR PRODUCTION SITES!
    controls: true,        // Whether or not to show the jQuery News Ticker controls
    titleText: 'Latest',   // To remove the title set this to an empty String
    displayType: 'reveal', // Animation type - current options are 'reveal' or 'fade'
    direction: 'ltr'       // Ticker direction - current options are 'ltr' or 'rtl'
    pauseOnItems: 2000,    // The pause on a news item before being replaced
    fadeInSpeed: 600,      // Speed of fade in animation
    fadeOutSpeed: 300      // Speed of fade out animation
);
```

});

Comment: Thank you - I had actually tried that before however again, it seemed to break the whole ticker. In the end I've re-downloaded all the JS files again.